# how to configure freeradius for separate Code and Password prompts, instead of a single Password prompt?

Tags: pam, freeradius

I've got a Freeradius server set up where the users in /etc/freeradius/users have `Auth-Type := PAM`. This makes radius refer to the /etc/pam.d/radiusd file, and in this file I have

```
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
auth sufficient pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

This works fine, but the issue is that it prompts only for a single Password, and the user is supposed to concatenate their unix password + google auth code. Then the google_authenticator module strips out the auth code, checks it, and forwards the remainder of the password to the next module.

As I said, it works fine, but I would like the user to be prompted twice: the first time for the Verification Code, and the second time for the unix Password. How to do this?

Comment: There's no way to do this. Which is why this procedure exists!

Comment: can you elaborate. does the radius server not have the capability to prompt twice?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the protocol for two factor authentication.

Comment: if this is the case, then why does the pam_radius_auth.so module have options for "prompt" and "force_prompt", whose purpose, according to the docs, is: "useful for multi-factor authentication when presenting the same prompt twice might confuse users ..." ... ?